# Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, solved?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

(Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`)

Is it okay if I set the ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] in config/boot.rb with this logic?

```
# config/boot.rb
require 'securerandom'
ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] = SecureRandom.hex
# outputs: 5b5cd0da3121fc53b4bc84d0c8af2e81
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `.env` file in root for production data. [Look at this gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)